# Unable to achieve TPS while using throughput controller along with Unique Each occurance parameterization customization

Tags: jmeter

I've to execute a test where one transaction can have multiple-lines (Eg: orders placed by different users in the real world where every user can have different cart size). In order to achieve this I have a products list and I need unique product at every occurrence. I have used a code similar to this "https://www.perfmatrix.com/jmeter-parameter-setting-unique-each-occurrence/" and I was able to achieve unique each occurrence. But the problem is when I am using a throughput controller and constant throughput timer I am not able to achieve desired TPS whereas hardcoded payload with various lines (with throughput controller and constant throughput timer) leads to desired TPS. Do we have any other options to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Beanshell Sampler might be the root cause of the problem, according to JMeter documentation [you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because using Beanshell is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, check out [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more details.

Another possible reason could be test data itself, for example request A is "light" and returns data in less than one second due to its request parameters and request "B" is "heavy" and returns data in more than 5 seconds.

Throughput of 100 requests A and 100 requests B will be different so you might need to add more threads.

Comment: I am using JSR223 for customization. JSR223 sampler. One to generate payload. Then one more inside loop controller to run for number of items in the cart size